# UTF8 Encoding not adding byte order mark

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

We know that the constructor of the class `UTF8Encoding` can receive an optional parameter: a `bool` specifying if the encoder should provide a byte order mark (BOM) or not.

However, when encoding the same text using both approaches, the output is the same:

```
string text = "Hello, world!";
byte[] withBom= new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
byte[] withoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(text);
```

Both `withBom` and `withoutBom` have the same content, one doesn't even have one byte more than the other one.

Why does this happen? Why is the byte order mark not being added to `withBom`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BOM parameter in the constructor does no affect the result of [`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getbytes.aspx), it affects the result of [`GetPreamble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getpreamble.aspx). Users are expected to append it manually.

```
byte[] bom = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetPreamble(); // 3 bytes
byte[] noBom = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetPreamble(); // 0 bytes
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know why one has to append the preamble manually?

Comment: @MatiCicero `GetBytes` can be used on partial output too, not only on the whole string. Producing BOM every time won't be helpful.

Comment: Haha, it's an honour!

Answer (score 3):

The BOM is returned via the [`UTF8Encoding.GetPreamble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getpreamble(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true);
byte[] withBom = enc.GetPreamble().Concat(enc.GetBytes(text)).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for showing me how to append it to my current encoded bytes

Comment: @MatiCicero I wouldn't recommend using this code for large strings though. This will produce too much garbage.